# How to select records that have apostrophe containers using the same words without apostrophe words?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to select records that have apostrophe containers using the same words without apostrophe words?

```
+----+------------------------------------------+-------+
| id | name                                     | price |
+----+------------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | World's Best Inspirational Books         | 199   |
|  2 | Ben Martin Men's Slim                    | 98    |
|  3 | Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone | 79    |
|  4 | Today's life                             | 690   |
|  5 | Life's Amazing Secrets                   | 99    |
+----+------------------------------------------+-------+
```

```
$search = "worlds";

SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE "%$search%";
```

I want this result from `$search = "world's";`

```
+----+------------------------------------+-------+
| id | name                               | price |
+----+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | World's Best Inspirational Books   | 199   |
+----+------------------------------------+-------+
```

But I got this, `Empty set (0.001 sec)`

How can I able to search `world's`(apostrophes) words (without including apostrophe them) using `worlds?

Comment: where replace(name, '''', '') like '%worlds%'

Comment: Cannot reproduce it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92830a48161220137698c17040c58b40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this works in mysql, but in sql server you can do this

```
declare @test table (name varchar(50))
insert into @test values ('World''s Best Inspirational Books'), 
                         ('Ben Martin Men''s Slim'),
                         ('Harry Potter and the Philosopher''s Stone'),
                         ('Today''s life'),
                         ('Life''s Amazing Secrets')

select * 
from   @test t
where  t.name like '%world_s%'
```

and it will return the first row.
So if you don't want to add extra `'` in your search, maybe you can replace all `'` with an `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape an apostrophe by doing:

```
World''s
```

In a program, a "dirty" way to fix it, is by adding an additional apostrophe ( ' ) to all instances within a parameter, before calling the query.

Comment: OP is using double quoted string

Comment: @SalmanA In that case OP can convert them to apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to know how to do it the other way around where you were searching for a value which contained an apostrophe but didn't know where. For example: assume you have a list of local basketball team names:

| TeamName | TotalTeamPoints |
| --- | --- |
| Ben's Crushers | 110 |
| Tommy Ballers | 94 |

```
select * from basketball_teams where TeamName like "%Bens Crushers%"
```

It would return a null set. But if you were to run

```
select * from basketball_teams where TeamName like "%Ben's Crushers%"
```

it would return the correct detail. The issue is, if you didn't know where the apostrophe belongs, it would be an impossible search unless you went through every entry manually.

**SOLUTION**

```
select * from basketball_teams where REPLACE(TeamName, "'", "") like "%Bens Crushers%";
```

Returns the correct data.